# Ambiguous reference to member 'first(where)'

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing migration UIWebView to WKWebView. After changing everything facing one error Ambiguous reference to member 'first(where)'. Help me to fix this issue.

```
UIWebView

func share(sender: UIWebView) {
        if let url: URL = webViews.first?.request?.url {
            do {
                let base64Data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let documentURL = try savePDF(base64Data)
                documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: documentURL)
                documentInteractionController?.presentOptionsMenu(from: shareButton, animated: true)
            } catch {
                displayAlert(Localizations.Error, message: Localizations.Apierror, responder: nil, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

I changed above code to WKWebView

```
WKWebView

func share(sender: WKWebView) {

        if let url: URL = webViews.first?.load?.url
        {
            do {
                let base64Data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let activityController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [base64Data], applicationActivities: nil)
                present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } catch {
                displayAlert(Localizations.Error, message: Localizations.Apierror, responder: nil, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

facing error in this line `if let url: URL = webViews.first?.load?.url`

Comment: What's the type of your `webViews`?

Comment: fileprivate let webViews: [WKWebView] @nyg

Comment: Can you show the code where you are adding items to webViews?

Comment: @Siva Did my answer help? Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Yes. Thank you @nyg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WKWebView` has no property `load`, only `load(_:)`. Maybe what you want to do is just:

```
if let url = webViews.first?.url {
    // ..
}
```